# How do i deal with data:img elements populating in my resources?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

Notice the data:img images... I dont know how to remove them from memory and document.images does not contain them...

[image: too many data:img being saved in memory and are slowing me down]

I am writing a Chrome Extension. Its somewhat of a hybrid screenshot app and basically when a user scrolls it takes the new part of the screen that the user has scrolled to and appends it on to a master screenshot of the entire site (yeah i have used googles screenshot app). My code works, but when I pass the img from the extension to the content script its storing the data:img sources into somewhere in memory where I cant access. I have tried document.images and tested to see if they may be populated within but with no luck.

Heres the code if you are interested.

**page.js**

```
var ovr = 0;
var run = (window==window.top)?1:0;
if(run&&ovr){
function obj(){
    window.onload = function(){
        obj.conversion = .5;
        obj.screenShot();
        obj.startRecordingScroll();
        obj.showShot(); 
    };

}
obj.showShot = function(){
    obj.fullShot = document.createElement('canvas');
    obj.fullShot.zIndex = -100;
    obj.fullShot.style.position = 'fixed';
    obj.fullShot.style.top = '70px';
    obj.fullShot.style.right = '20px';
    obj.fullShot.style.backgroundColor = '#999999';
    obj.fullShot.width = window.innerWidth*obj.conversion;
    obj.fullShot.height = document.height*obj.conversion;
    document.body.appendChild(obj.fullShot);
    obj.ctx = obj.fullShot.getContext('2d');
};
obj.startRecordingScroll = function(){
    document.onscroll = function(){
        obj.scroll();
    };
};
obj.scroll = function(){
    var pagxoff = window.pageXOffset;
    var pagyoff = window.pageYOffset;
    alert(document.images.length);
    console.log("scroll");
    obj.screenShot();

};
obj.displayScreenShot = function(img){
    console.log('displayScreenShot');
    var ycur = window.pageYOffset;
    var yMaxCur = window.innerHeight+window.pageYOffset;
    var distance = yMaxCur - obj.lastMaxYSeen;
    distance = Math.abs(distance);
    if(!obj.firstRunShot){
        obj.lastMinYSeen = window.pageYOffset;
        obj.lastMinXSeen = window.pageXOffset;
        obj.lastMaxYSeen = (window.innerHeight+window.pageYOffset);
        obj.lastMaxXSeen = (window.innerWidth+window.pageXOffset);
        var shot = document.createElement('img');
        shot.src = img;
        console.log(img);
        shot.onload = function(){
            obj.ctx.drawImage(
                shot,
                0, // 0 right
                0, // 0 down
                window.innerWidth, // viewport width
                window.innerHeight, // viewport height
                0, // 0 right
                0, // 0 down
                window.innerWidth*obj.conversion,
                window.innerHeight*obj.conversion
            );
        };
        obj.firstRunShot = true;
        return;
    }

    if(obj.firstRunShot){
        if(ycur>obj.lastMinYSeen){
            obj.lastMinYSeen = window.pageYOffset;
            obj.lastMinXSeen = window.pageXOffset;
            obj.lastMaxYSeen = (window.innerHeight+window.pageYOffset);
            obj.lastMaxXSeen = (window.innerWidth+window.pageXOffset);
            var xshot = document.createElement('img');
            xshot.src = img;
            xshot.onload = function(){
                obj.ctx.drawImage(
                    xshot,
                    0,
                    window.innerHeight-distance,
                    window.innerWidth,
                    distance,
                    0,
                    (obj.lastMaxYSeen-distance)*obj.conversion,
                    window.innerWidth*obj.conversion,
                    (distance)*obj.conversion
                );
            };
            return;
        }
    }
};
obj.screenShot = function(){
    var port = chrome.extension.connect({
        name: "screenshot"
    });
    port.postMessage({
        request: "screenshot"
    });
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
        obj.displayScreenShot(msg);
    });
    console.log('screenShot');
};

var builder = new obj();
}
```

Comment: aren't these data:image objects just canvas elements? try enumerating canvases in the DOM to see if they are there.

Comment: i will check, i am supposed to only create the canvas element once which is called fullShot. I think the code is creating img elements and appending the img element to the fullShot... lets try it out

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('canvas').length is only showing one every time a scroll happens so no that didnt work :(

Comment: how many frames does the document have? are you looking at the right frame?

Comment: I am checking the correct frame... and I am not seeing the solution to the 'checking the entire DOM' thought you mean have a list of elements and loop throught them and then check their contents that way?

Comment: then i misunderstood the question. please define "content script" that you mention in your post and how you use it.

Comment: the page.js is my content script... but it is being called from a localhost server and being eval'd... if that does anything or may affect me in any way

Comment: @user1874111: are you looking to storage canvas image to disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can track resources being [added](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#event-onResourceAdded) and [manipulate](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-Resource-setContent) all contents of these resources using `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow` API's, if you want to delete some resource modify DOM by deleting node(s).

document.images does contain the resources.

[image]

The [Resources panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources) lets you inspect resources that are loaded in the inspected page, are you loading your image into inspected page to show up here?

If you are trying to store image to local disk using [FILE API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), remember they are sand-boxed and cannot be accessed by other means.

### References

- [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html)
- [`Resources Panel`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/resources)
- [`File API`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)
- [`Content Scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)